# Change Border Color of DataGrid based on Property in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a Combobox and a DataGrid. I want to be able to select a value in the Combobox (SelectedItem is databound to a Property of the ViewModel). If the cell value of a specific column in the DataGrid matches the combobox value, I want to change the entire row's border color. I've found ways to change the border color of the DataGrid using a converter but the ConverterParameter can't be bound to the SelectedItem Property because it's not a DependancyProperty or DependancyObject. Any ideas as to how I can do this? Thanks!

Comment: Why not use Javascript....specifically Jquery?

Comment: It's a WPF desktop application.

Comment: Sorry I should've read the tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use multi-binding with multi-value converter in the `DataTriggers` of your `DataGridRow.Style`:

Xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MultiConverter x:Key="multiConv"/>
</Window.Resources>
...

    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModel.MyList}" >
        <DataGrid.RowStyle >
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Value="true">
                        <DataTrigger.Binding>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource multiConv}">
                                <Binding Path="ColorColumn" />
                                <Binding Path="ViewModel.SelectedColor" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                AncestorType=Window}"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    </DataGrid>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModel.ColorList}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding ViewModel.SelectedColor}"/>
```

Multi-value converter:

```
public class MultiConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values[0] is MyColorType &&
            values[1] is MyColorType &&
            // if ComboBox.SelectedColor == CurrentDataGridRow.ColorColumn
            (MyColorType)values[0] == (MyColorType)values[1])
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(
        object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I also found this method after I posted the original question. What I did instead was added a Brush property to the ViewModel for the record and databound the Value of the setter for the BorderBrush to this new property which seemed like the simpler way of getting the job done. I'll likely change it to this method when I have some extra time though. Thanks @Bahman_Aries !!